# what is the effect of shifting an integer zero times?

Tags: java

i just spotted this in [DirectByteBuffer.slice()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice):

```
public ByteBuffer slice() {
    int pos = this.position();
    int lim = this.limit();
    assert (pos <= lim);
    int rem = (pos <= lim ? lim - pos : 0);
    int off = (pos << 0); // <---- what does this do
    assert (off >= 0);
    return new DirectByteBuffer(this, -1, 0, rem, rem, off);
}
```

what is the point of shifting an int left by 0 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before that class's declaration, there is the following comment:

```
// -- This file was mechanically generated: Do not edit! -- //
```

The code generation scheme that was used probably didn't bother to get rid of shifts by 0, even though they have no effect.